# Lamp doesnt work properly after upgrade ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I have the basics knowledge about installing apache, configuring, vhosts, etc.

I had taskseel lamp installed on my ubuntu 12.04 and i tried this steps to install lastest version of php 5 for work with all the Symfony2 functions:

http://www.barryodonovan.com/index.php/2012/05/22/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-and-php-5-4-again

I dont know exactly if that steps "make" more changes.

Every time i tried to access to my old vhosts i get the Apache2 Debian Default Page.

Before the upgrade i access to phpmyadmin at localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php, now i create a symlink and i can access to phpmyadmin login page at localhost/phpmyadmin/, but then the login redirect me to index.php i get 404 not found.

I checked the vhosts, the apache.conf and can find any clue on what happens.

Either i cant load the info.php y have in /var/www/info.php.

It looks like maybe apache was upgraded to 2.4.9 and it broke or unconfigure something.

Must i do a fresh installation of apache2, phpmyadmin and all or i can fix it?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

**VHOSTS SOLVED**

I solved the vhosts problem doing 2 things:

1. In the apache2.conf i added another line because i rename all my vhosts as .local

   /# Include the virtual host configurations:

   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.local
2. After that i was getting a 403 forbidden so in a simple search i found:

   [Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden)

Where Phil L says that Require all granted is New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3

**Phpmyadmin Problem**

After long time searching finally i found a clue at:

http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/72878#.U1OPt3WSxUc

The problem was that the apache2.conf dont have the route to the phpmyadmin.conf file, so the include solved the problem.

I hope this helps other mates, i loose some hours with this.