# Trouble setting up Apache 2.4.9 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache, unix, httpd.conf

*Since upgrading to OS X Yosemite DP I have had trouble using Apache on my Mac, and previously fell back to using MAMP. Since OS X 10.10 DP5, now MAMP does not work either. So I figured I had to fix this issue the hard way (I am not very skilled with raw server setup). I have tried however, without success, and I do now know where to look next.*

This is what I have done:

[image]

After seeing this result I of course checked if the Aoache service was indeed running:

[image]

OK. Then I figured it must indeed have been my Apache configuration that was wrong. And rightfully so, prompting `apachectl` in Terminal I found that the Apache config had parsing errors (probably because Apache was updated when updating to OS X 10.10, but the config file not following? Anyway, I followed instructions to get a valid config file with a minimum of installed modules (`.so`-files taken from location of previous installation).

[image]

A copy of my `httpd.conf` can be seen on http://pastebin.com/VU5aZ6vL, but key variables are listed here:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
User daemon
Group daemon
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/Users/casparjespersen/Sites/"
```

***Still, the result is the same. Any ideas where to look next?***

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start and it solves the issue with MAMP

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Because in the Apache 2.4.3+  was added a new security feature. Adding 'Require all granted' in each vhost fixes that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Quick fix: http://www.ampps.com/ does still work for me for a basic Apache/MySQL setup.

But AMPPS lacks of many great features I love with MAMP.

Comment: It's weird. I hope someone else has a better solution. I'll try AMPPS though.

Comment: They have found a better solution in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start).

Answer (score 1):

This will help you just follow the instructions:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 1):

After researching setting up Apache on Yosemite this issue was explained - the solution is to implicitly add localhost at the top, before your Virtualhost block pointing to 127.0.0.1...  Sorry I can seem to find the YouTube link that explained this.