# MAMP Pro 3.05 on Mavericks updated to Yosemite - Apache does not start

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks, mamp, mamp-pro

I have been running MAMP Pro 3.05 successfully in Yosemite up to DP4 on a partition that was a clean install of Yosemite.

I now have run the installer for DP5 over my Mavericks install, and now that MAMP Pro install will not start Apache.  It says to check the logs, but I don't see anything pertinent.

I'm assuming that since this is a pre-existing install, something in its config is wrong for Yosemite's Apache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 733, accepted):

MAMP Folks just [posted](https://twitter.com/mamp_en/status/496668261619335169) the workaround

Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: Rename the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”

**Test Update: It works!**

**Works for Yosemite release too!**

Comment: Worked for me.  Really weird.  Why does this fix it?

Comment: One of the Apache modules used in MAMP (I forgot which one - this happened some time ago) used a copy that was shipped with the Mac OS. That module's location was changed in Yosemite leading to it not being found anymore by the path defined in "envvars" when we rename the file, we are letting MAMP find the module on it's own without any predefined paths.

Comment: thanks! great! stopped working for me, too when upgrading to yosemite!

Comment: This did not work for me the first time ... I had copied "envvars" to "_envvars" rather than renaming, and it was not until I removed the original "envvars" that Apache successfully started.

Comment: The solution was to "rename" the file, not copy to _envars. The solution is that the original file should not exist then MAMP will work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me... and apache error logs are empty.

Comment: Apache started, but MySQL will not.

Answer (score 28):

Just found workaround from MAMP on Twitter

Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: 
Rename the file “envvars” located in  into “_envvars”

Answer (score 12):

This works also for Mamp Pro 2.1.1 on Yosemite.

> MAMP Folks just posted the workaround
>
> Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: Rename the file “envvars”
>   located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”
>
> Test Update: It works!

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the MAMP folks are working on a work-around:

https://twitter.com/mamp_en/status/496655943506350081

Follow their account for updates.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP Pro 3.0.7.3 should run fine on Yosemite, but after installing it on a brand new machine, I experienced the same problem.

In my case, the problem occurred because I had defined Additional Parameters for my virtual host that contained quotes. By default, Yosemite keyboard settings are set to convert straight quotes to smart quotes ("no-cache" became “no-cache”. Depending on font and font size, this may not be immediately obvious). This made Apache crash, even when the host was disabled.

To change this settings, go to System Preferences -> Keyboard. In the Text tab, uncheck Use smarts quotes and dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I upgraded to MAMP Pro 3.0.7.3 after I upgraded to OSX Yosemite 10.10 (official release) and I experienced this same problem. Apache could not start and it has an empty log file.

I tried this fix, but I noticed that the file is named "envvars_" not "envvars". I renamed it to envvars, restarted MAMP Pro and apache could not start and it had an empty log file. I also noticed that the envvars file had been renamed to envvars_ after I had renamed it.

Comment: I also have noticed the same rename, and the problem is still unfixed. Looks like it's getting to be time to ditch Mamp.

Comment: @frumbert before you ditch it, try to set the PHP version to be dynamic for each host. That seems to of fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was running MAMP 3.0.5 on Mavericks. After upgrading Mavericks to El Capitan, I ran into the same issue. Mysql did start normally but Apache did not.

After renaming `envvars` to `_envvars` in the folder `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin` such as suggested for Yosemite, I was able to start Apache as before.

So, this fix works for El Capitan as well!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it working by changing envvar to _envvar but was able to resolve by changing the apache port from 8888 to 80 then noticed I was missing the mod_example.so. See how I resolved below:

[Why won't Apache Server start in MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252124/why-wont-apache-server-start-in-mamp/29522852#29522852)

Answer (score 0):

I tried that solution and others over and over and did not work until I realised I should be restarting completely MAMP, after doing so, this simple change from envvars to _envvars worked like a charm.

You can completely restart MAMP checking if there's any process going on, open the terminal:

```
ps -cvx | grep "mysql"
```

That will output a list of the processes that involves mysql at the time, with a PDI associated, so you only have to take that number and:

```
kill PDI
```

Where PDI is the number associated to the process, after that, if you write again the command `ps -cvx | grep "mysql"` the pointer should be empty.

Once done, only execute MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer didn't work for me because the _envvars file was already there. I had to download the latest version of MAMP and install it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's not always the `envars` files that's the culprit. If you've been editing the vhost file at `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, a syntax error could cause MAMP's apache to not start without a warning.

In that case, you can run the following command and see if any errors are encountered.

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

Rename the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars” only for OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I got MAMP v3.4 working.

I renamed "envars_" to "_envars" ... but that didn't work.

I had to also go into preferences, and hit the "Set Web & MySql ports to 80 & 3306" button!

Works!