# Laravel 404 on every page, but shows directory after Yosemite update

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I updated to Yosemite about 3 hours ago; now all my Laravel projects show a 404 page when trying to load ANY route. It 'lists' the files when trying to go to the `home` route?

I created a new Laravel project and it works just fine; how can I fix this?

Here is what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there is data there; mamp is running just fine. So I cannot figure out why it is not working?

Comment: What are you using to host it? MAMP?

Comment: Try removing the `/` from your route.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff I have done that, same result

Comment: @user2957677 Yes, I am using MAMP

Comment: Hit road/public/index.php and tell me the result.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff exact same result, 404 not found on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a new project via `Terminal` and coppied the code (I tried just dragging the files in `finder` and it gave the same results. So I created new files, and literally coppied the code and it worked just fine. I have no clue what it is, weird.

Comment: If you use git for code management you could try taking your old files and your new files and doing a diff. Did you try updating Laravel or anything else?

Comment: I am not using git for this project unfortunately. But I plan to in the future. I did not try updating Laravel, even though, it still is weird how the yosemite update broke MAMP and the laravel projects

Comment: If it keeps happening I would move the project into a Virtual Machine so you can isolate where the problem is. This would give you a clear indication if its MAMP or Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with MAMP more than Laravel. I run Laravel with Homestead and when I updated to Yosemite everything worked fine after restarting my VM. [You may look at this post. Apache may not be starting on MAMP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start)

```
MAMP Folks just posted the workaround

Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: Rename the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”

Test Update: It works!
```

If you get the courage as well you should really [give Homestead a shot](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) for developing with a Laravel. I even use it for Wordpress and everything else.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, it got apache to start, yes, but Still this my projects won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the comment (#) from the beginning of LoadModule php5_module in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to enable PHP after updating to Yosemite, you may have to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yosemite does some serious changes to the environment. Apache is updated from 2.2 to 2.4, so one should check the httpd configuration.

PHP is updated from 5.4 to 5.5 - if you have had a working mcrypt module, you will have to reinstall that too.
This is the most referenced link: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/

What worked for me was updating XCode to 6.1 and then

> brew update
>
> brew install php55-mcrypt.

Be sure to link the correct php Module in your /etc/httpd.conf afterwards.