# Mamp Pro 3.0.7.3 and Yosemite 10.10

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp-pro

I've send a ticket to the Mamp people but in the mean time... I just updated to Mamp Pro 3.0.7.3 and I cannot get a Wordpress build to load nor can I get into my phpMyAdmin.  Anybody have this issue yet? I can see the url ping the localhost then it goes to "/" followed by site unavailable. Can't seem to find if I've missed a preference so I pretty sure it has to do with the update + i'm on Yosemite.

thanks!

Comment: No log, no error, no help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MAMP Pro 3.05 on Mavericks updated to Yosemite - Apache does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

Ticket came back it is a glitch in 3.0.7.3 expect and update everyone