# Upgrading to MAMP 3: “The installation cannot be continued!”

Tags: dns, installation, mamp

I’m trying to upgrade my current MAMP installation to the latest version (3.0.7.3). I have quit the current version and tried to run the installation package.

Each time, the installation have failed: “The installation cannot be continued!”

And I’m served with the following instruction: “Please quit MAMP / MAMP PRO as well as all servers and deactivate the Dynamic DNS Services before you restart the installation process.”

I’ve tried to run the installation while connected to the internet and not connected, to no avail. I don’t quite know what this Dynamic DNS Service is about.

Any advice or suggestion to troubleshoot this issue?

Many thanks,

P.

Comment: FWIW I would propose this question be edited to refer to all MAMP versions. Currently I'm having this EXACT issue upgrading from MAMP 4.2 to MAMP 4.4.x. Would be nice to have an ongoing answer that applies to the ongoing problem where this KEEPS happening to people. (incidentally, my problem was solved by one of the answers below, so it's version independent: Turn off servers INSIDE MAMP, then quit, then update. Just quitting doesn't work.)

Answer (score 21):

In my case, I needed to kill all mysqld and httpd processes before it would install. Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo killall mysqld
sudo killall httpd
```

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same issue. The solution was to stop the default mysql server which is included in OS X:

Open Application -> Utilities -> Activity Monitor

Search for mysqld in the process list and stop it. The MAMP PRO installation will work now.

Answer (score 6):

I started mamp again after the install failed and found that apache was still marked as running. I stopped apache through the mamp interface, closed mamp, and then ran the installer again and it worked.

Comment: THIS! Thank you Mike for this obvious but counter-intuitive advice! Turning of MAMP is not enough on it's own! It leaves some vestige remaining. (especially in my case where my MAMP 4.2 was hanging and had to be force quitted to work). 

Definitely recommend everyone try this before renaming any files etc.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same error message when trying to install MAMP Pro 3.0.7.3 on Yosemite 10.10.1. I was upgrading from MAMP Pro 2 and every time I ran the package, the installation failed. For me, deleting the previous versions of MAMP and MAMP Pro folders and rebooting my computer allowed me to successfully install the new version. All of my hosts and settings were preserved during the upgrade. Hope that helps or you've already figured out an answer to your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and yes, it helps a lot. When you write that you deleted the previous version, you mean the actual applications located inside the MAMP and MAMP Pro folders, in Applications? You left everything else in place? I’m asking because de hosts are located in those folders as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), there is an [acknowledged bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141849) that prevents MAMP from starting Apache. I wasn't unable to upgrade to version 3 until I addressed the Apache bug.

To resolve the issue, you need to simply rename a file in your MAMP directory:

```
$ cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
$ mv envvars _envvars
```

After closing MAMP and renaming that file, the installation package ran without issue. Another way to address this, as suggested above, is to delete your MAMP/MAMP Pro directories entirely.

I would start with a file rename first before uninstalling MAMP or deleting any directories!