# MAMP Apache couldn't be started

Tags: php, apache, mamp

On MacOSX when using MAMP GUI to start, MySQL starts but Apache doesn't start and gives the following error

`Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration`

running `sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start` gives

`httpd: Syntax error on line 135 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/modules/libphp7.so, 10): Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/modules/libphp7.so\n  Reason: image not found`

Additional info
 - I've downloaded PHP 7.0.10 from https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/
 - I'm using MAMP not MAMP Pro

EDIT:

I've tried

- Renaming the file “envvars” located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”
- Changing ports

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't Apache Server start in MAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252124/why-wont-apache-server-start-in-mamp)

Comment: @ThomasEdwards 10.11.6

Comment: @aynber If you look at geoidesic's comment you'll notice the given error is different than the original post and there is no answer for this particular error.

Comment: I reacted the close vote (There was some hinkiness when I was rereading the post), but the troubleshooting steps outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29522852/1007220  might help narrow down why this is happening

Comment: @aynber I did post the result of that. If you try to google the error message you'll see this post first and non of the results have a solution which I haven't tried yet. I followed stackoverflow rules being specific, trying other answers provided and then posted this question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260612/4335588

Comment: That envvars you renamed is probably a "hint" file of what you should add inside Apache HTTPD own envvars file, so when it is started it loads into LD_LIBRARY_PATH the paths for the necessary libs needed by "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/modules/libphp7.so". Issue a `ldd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/modules/libphp7.so` and make sure all necessary libs get loaded in httpd's own envvars when apache httpd is invoked.