# Apache doesn't start in MAMP, error shows Cannot create SSLMutex Configuration Failed

Tags: apache, mamp

When I try to start Apache in my MAMP installation, I keep getting the error:

```
[error] (2)No such file or directory: Cannot create SSLMutex
Configuration Failed
```

This error has started coming all of sudden. :( Everything was fine until yesterday. I have looked at various solutions like the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start?rq=1). That didn't work. Changing the port number also didn't work.

What's the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Today this happened to me, but running Sierra with the latest updates. I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421367/mamp-not-working-after-sierra-osx-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing started happening to me today (until a few days ago everything was working). I updated OSX to Sierra and that seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: That's very odd. I'll try that today & let you know if it helps.

Comment: Updating to Sierra worked. Apache now starts for me on MAMP 3.5. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea why would that happen? What happens when the OS is updated to Sierra?