# MAMP not working after Sierra OSX update

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, macos-sierra

I am using MAMP version 3.2 with Sierra OSX v10.12. After installing a recent update to Sierra, MAMP is refusing to start.

In the `apache_error.log` file under `/Applications/MAMP/logs`, I see the following error:

`[Fri Nov 04 10:16:51 2016] [error] (2)No such file or directory: Cannot create SSLMutex
Configuration Failed`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering if you can install a new version of MAMP? If not, check permissions of `/tmp` folder

Try changing permission to `chmod 777 tmp`

Comment: Actually, thanks to  Gilles... the actual permissions should be  for /tmp are 1777, which ls shows as drwxrwxrwt.

Comment: Exactly! seems like `1777` gives rights only to the owner for deleting files, important in a multi-user environment.