# 403 Access forbidden with Virtual Hosts

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

My server is running Apache under Arch Linux. I was running server for one domain then I bought new domain yesterday and I wanted to create virtual hosts for each domains. I have followed this arch linux LAMP tutorial and created vhosts folder and two separate text files for each domain. I have included them in the last line of httpd.conf. Restarted the server and both domains gives me 403.

I double-checked permissions in `httpd.conf` and my filesystem. Both of my Document Roots has permission of 777 in filesystem and "Require all granted" in vhost config file. I have looked at error and access logs that is generated at each document roots and they are empty. I can't seem to figure what's the problem. I'm pretty sure it's not the filesystem permissions. I think perhaps httpd.conf or vhost files are missing something?

Config Files
[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/TUQKDL5S)

[vhost](http://pastebin.com/kipF9bCD) of mybusiness.net (named changed for privacy)

other vhost is similar to mybusiness.net. I would post link here but stackoverflow wont allow me to post more than two links.

My first domain is located at `/home/public_html` and my second domain is located at my own directory, `/home/tom/http/tomawebsite`

My hosts file:

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost   amaranth
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.0.1   mybusiness.net
127.0.0.1   tomawebsite.com
# End of file
```

Comment: what are your permissions on the document root ?

Comment: chmod 777 and "Require all granted" for both virtual hosts

Comment: what about chown ? you might need those permissions sorting

Comment: also have you even searched ? for similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden?rq=1

Comment: I'll try that. I will report back on the result.

Comment: Chown does not work and I have already searched for threads like that. I have tried following the steps from those threads but it would not work. Would it help if I posted my httpd.conf and virtual hosts file?

Comment: maybe post your hosts file and basic directory structure