# LARAVEL - JQuery AJAX 403 Forbidden

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to import jquery library in my Laravel project, in my firebug i'm seeing the message:

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://test.local/js/jquery_min.js"

Why is LARAVEL blocking my script, to be loaded?

Comment: Where is laravel run from? This looks suspiciously like a browser preventing the loading of local resources.

Comment: Yes as you can see he's preventing the script to be loaded properly. The server is local server, Apache, and i made virtual host for this project.

Comment: Make sure the directory is readable by apache. Since it's a static file it has nothing to do with laravel.

Comment: I saw article for problem like mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden    , but still i cant fix the problem.

Comment: Check the files/directories _permissions_.

Comment: Thank you guys for assisting me. I found the problem.  New Apache 2.4 maybe earlier versions, have added new security features.... If you had the same problem as i you must the next things. 1. You must go to your virtual host configuration with command " sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-name-of-the-site.conf".  2. Put Requred all granted  <Directory "/site/directory">
                     AllowOverride All
                     Allow from All
                     Require all granted   
                    </Directory>   Then type sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/apache3

Comment: The same command for your site directory and restart apache and it will work.

Comment: Don't set the permissions to 777. Set it to 755.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be error in file to access or file name may be wrong

check whether the file name is jquery_min.js or jquery.min.js, if file name was right then try access with cdn :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
 in script tag

Notify if you found any solutions
Thank you