# Can't see images in localhost

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I'm starting to develop a site in `ubuntu 14.04`. I'm using `apache2`, so I placed my files under `/var/www/html/` folder. Everything was working fine, but I had to restart my current work so I copied the entire project folder from another path, like this

```
$ sudo cp ~/path/to/folder /var/www/html/
```

And now I can't see my images, a simple `img`tag. I just see this.

[image]

When I look for the file, I can see that I'm having an error 403 forbidden. I saw some [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden) to add the option `Require all granted` but that option is already set in my apache. I suspect that is because the new folder is a copy from a folder without root permissions, so I tried chmod but that also didn't work so I'm completly lost now.

So, how can I see my images from localhost? and most important is why this happen suddenly?

Comment: Post the verbatim error log entry and the verbatim image URL.

Comment: who owns the newly copied folder?