# Why it shows 403 forbidden when I added virtualhost on apache 2.4

Tags: apache

This's my configure file on apache 2.4

[image]

After restart,It shows me 403 page.
Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden)

Comment: You need to allow access to the documents: `Order allow,deny
Allow from all`.