# Apache 403 forbidden on allow from all <Directory> - virtualhosts

Tags: mysql, apache

Getting a 403 error on `DocumentRoot` for my `httpd-vhosts` file. '

**NOTE: I'm on MAC OSX Sierra 10.12**

The tutorial I'm following is [here](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/) - as instructed I ran `chmod 755 /sites/blog/my-website/web` but it didn't fix the issue. I also ran as `sudo` but was unsuccessful.

It is important to note I flushed my cache and restarted after running `chmod` with the following commands:

`sudo apachectl restart`

`dscacheutil -flushcache`

In httpd.conf file, I have the following line uncommented (again as instructed by tutorial):

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` configuration is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/sites"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/sites/blog/my-website/web"
        ServerName mywebsite.dev
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/connor.local-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/connor.local-access_log" common

        <Directory "/sites/blog/my-website/web">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? If more info is needed let me know.

Comment: Yep it is... I found my answer in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache VirtualHost 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden)

Is what fixed it. Quote from answer:

> Apache 2.4.3 (or maybe slightly earlier) added a new security feature
>   that often results in this error. You would also see a log message of
>   the form "client denied by server configuration". The feature is
>   requiring a user identity to access a directory. It is turned on by
>   DEFAULT in the httpd.conf that ships with Apache. You can see the
>   enabling of the feature with the directive

I needed to add `Require all granted` in `<Directory></Directory>`