# Apache 2.4 server 403 error despite permissions and server settings

Tags: localhost, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

I have a localhost Apache 2.4 server running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with DocumentRoot at var/www/html. If I try to access anything other than localhost/www/ (which contains a Nette index.php file), I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Now, this problem is common, and I have found numerous questions (exhibits [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden), [C](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/apache-403-forbidden), [D](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/), [E](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)) related to it. However, in this case:

- The server has never even seen Apache 2.2; it's a fresh install of 2.4.
- I have tried restarting the server *and* the entire computer. I even tried reinstalling apache2 through `apt`.
- All files and directories in var/www/html/ have 755 permissions. I have verified this for affected files using `ls -l`.
- DocumentRoot in etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf is set to var/www/html.
- In etc/apache2/apache.conf, there is this directory configuration:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The Apache error log says:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/debug/adminer-4.8.1.php
```

I am at a loss for what else might be causing this. Is there anything I overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked a `.htaccess` file with "Require all denied". Removing this file (or, in fact, changing the folder structure so that it would deny reasonable things) fixed the issue.